# Setting language not working after "Reset Content and Settings"

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

After pressing in my iOS simulator "Reset Content and Settings", the next time that I open my iOS application the language is not set.

I set my language in the following method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```

Using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"es", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

But when I open my app for the first time after Resetting I see just the keys that are in my file Localizable.strings. If I run the application again everything works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be because changing the language at runtime is not possible in iOS apps, at least using your solution. You have to restart the application before anything happens.

But, unless you have specific requirements (let's say, supporting multiple languages for a language learning app, for instance), changing the app's language at runtime is a bad and highly discouraged idea.

Comment: How can I just set the language (I dont want to change it)?